# how to count consecutive month that is present in a data frame by id using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Using Python, I need to count, by id, how many consecutive months exist, leading up to the month of the row. This is a running count that should restart once there was a missing month. Here is an example, with the desired outcome in the output column.

```
date <- c("01-01-2021", "02-01-2021", "03-01-2021", "05-01-2021", "06-01-2021", "01-01-2021", "03-01-2021", "04-01-2021")
ID <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b")
output <- c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2)
data.frame(date=as.Date(date), id=id, output=output)
```

For id "a," the count broke and restarted from May because April doesn't exist for "a." Same for "b," Feb didn't exist so count restarted from March.

How can I get output column?

Comment: Can you provide **python**, not **R** code?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.to_datetime(["01-01-2021", "02-01-2021", "03-01-2021", "05-01-2021", "06-01-2021", "01-01-2021", "03-01-2021", "04-01-2021"], format="%m-%d-%Y")
ids = ["a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b"]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": ids,
    "dates": dates
})

streaks = df["dates"].dt.to_period('M').diff().ne(pd.offsets.MonthEnd()).cumsum()
df["output"] = streaks.groupby(streaks).transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x) + 1))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  ID      dates  output
0  a 2021-01-01       1
1  a 2021-02-01       2
2  a 2021-03-01       3
3  a 2021-05-01       1
4  a 2021-06-01       2
5  b 2021-01-01       1
6  b 2021-03-01       1
7  b 2021-04-01       2
```